# CompletableFuture streaming on multiple argument lists

Tags: java, list, java-stream, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I'm trying to understand few concepts (stream, map, CompleteableFuture) and came up with an example to ask my doubt. I have two array lists. First list contains all accountIds and second list has their corresponding passwords.

How can I stream over these 2 lists parallely when these 2 lists are passed as parameters to `someFunction()`?

```
List<String> accountIds = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>(); 

accountIds.stream().map(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
return someFunction(accountIds.get(i), passwords.get(i)); // Each item of the list needs to be passed, not the whole list
}, EXECUTORS));
```

This streams over 'accountIds'. But how can I parallely stream over 'passwords'?

Comment: I am not quite sure about the requriment. But what I am able to understand is you want to iterate over two (equal size) list simultaneosly and pass both the element to some list. If this is so there are lot of ways. 

One of them is using IntStream.
IntStream.range(0, accountIds.size()).forEach(i -> someFunction(accountIds.get(i),passwords.get(i)));

Comment: @Holger, I need to call '''someFunction()''' on every item in the list. I should not be passing the complete list as a parameter. Edited my question to include this detail.

Comment: @TusharJajodia, I need to use CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync so that someFunction() gets called on every item in accountIds and passwords list and this should happen asynchronously. I'm not quite sure if using IntStream guarantees async.

Comment: Then Tushar Jajodia’s suggestion is sufficient. You don’t need specific guarantees from the `IntStream`, as that’s what the `CompletableFuture` is for, `IntStream.range(0, accountIds.size()).map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> someFunction(accountIds.get(i), passwords.get(i)), EXECUTORS))` etc.